# Thinking of extending BeforeAll so it would take care of login

Tags: typescript, playwright, playwright-test

We are using playwright to write integration-tests. One of the things were are trying to do is to minimize the code in the actual test itself and do more behind the scenes.

To explain this a bit further, if we were writing integration-tests for a particular page, we would like the state of our application to be set to that page even before we start writing the test. We have set up our page object model to achieve exactly this.

Currently, we are trying to implement a design where in we will be logged into the application even before the first BeforeAll is executed. We are thinking of implementing it something like this -

```js
test.beforeAll(()=>{
     //code
}, {username: "name"})
```

What we expect the above code block to do is to log into the application for the provided username behind the scenes and then run the code inside of BeforeAll block.

However, I found that playwright does not provide way to extend beforeAll. Can you please suggest possible solutions?

I am aware of the globalSetup and StorageState approach but that happens in the global scope. So, if I were to use 5 different users during the entire duration of test execution, I will need to login and store the state of all the users at once. This might affect the performance when I am interested in using only two users as it will still login for all the five users at the beginning of execution.

I also thought of extending the page fixture and implementing the login logic over there but I do not believe we can pass parameters (in this case username) to the base.extend( ) function.

Thank you for reading this post and appreciate your responses.

Comment: Have you found a solution for your problem? Right now i'm facing a similar challenge. Thanks in advance for any feedback or tipp!

Answer (score 0):

You can define custom [fixtures](https://playwright.dev/docs/next/test-fixtures) to achieve that.

```
// fixtures.js
const base = require('@playwright/test');

module.exports = base.test.extend({
  loginUser: [ async ({}, use) => {
    const getLoggedInUser = (username) => {
      console.log('Decide how to (lazily?) allocate the user based on the username ' + username);
      return 'User: ' + username;
    };
    await use(getLoggedInUser);
    console.log('Do cleanup after all');
  }, { scope: 'worker', auto: true } ],
});
```

Then call the fixture from `beforeAll`:

```
// example.spec.js
const test = require('./fixtures');

test.beforeAll(({ loginUser }) => {
  loginUser('User 1');
})

test('test 1', async ({  }) => {
});
```

Or call it directly from the tests:

```
// example-2.spec.js
const test = require('./fixtures');

test('test 2', async ({ loginUser }) => {
  loginUser('User 2');
});
```

`getLoggedInUser` can decide whether to use existing state or create/login a new user. Note that this code will run in each playwright worker so you will need to somehow synchronize between them.